# android application icon launcher strange behaviiour

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

i created an application using android studio and referenced to the app name and app icon with dynamic reference to String file and drawable files and when i tried to change the app name and app icon with new one the application is installed with the old name and old icon and if i clicked uninstall the app uninstall confirmation dialog appears with the new icon and new name

my manifest application tag

```
<application
        android:name="main.app.misc.MainApplication"
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@drawable/launcher_demo"
        android:label="@string/demo_appName"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CustomTheme" >
```

and my launcher activity

```
 <activity
            android:name="main.app.welcome.Splash"
            android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

can any one help me

Comment: are you using any custom launcher or testing in MI phones, the launchers generally cache the app icons and names, so it will not reflect

Comment: no i'm not using custom launcher ,, and i'm testing on htc desire 820 device with api 4.4.4

Comment: Rebuild the project.

Comment: Already did clean and rebuild

Comment: Did you try installing in some other new mobile??

Comment: Thanks all ,it is a device defect and after restarting the device all things are working fine